# Difference between this and self in self-type annotations?

Tags: scala

In various Scala literature I see some self-type annotations using "this" and others using "self":

```
trait A { this: B => ... }
trait A { self: B => ... }
```

Is there any real difference between using "this" or "self"?  Does it matter at all what name you use?  Is this just as valid?

```
trait A { foo: B => ... }
```

Answer (score 187, accepted):

All three forms are valid, and have the effect that `B` is assumed as the type of `this` in class `A`.

The first two variants

```
trait A { self: B => ... }
trait A { foo: B => ... }
```

introduce `self` (respectively, `foo`) as an alias for `this` in trait `A`. This is useful for accessing the `this` reference from an inner class. I.e. you could then use `self` instead of `A.this` when accessing the `this` reference of the trait `A` from a class nested within it. Example:

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame { frame =>    
  getContentPane().add( new JButton( "Hide" ) {
    addActionListener( new ActionListener {
      def actionPerformed( e: ActionEvent ) {
        // this.setVisible( false ) --> shadowed by JButton!
        frame.setVisible( false )
      }
    })
  })
}
```

The third variant,

```
trait A { this: B => ... }
```

does not introduce an alias for `this`; it just sets the self type.

Comment: The way I look at self type is that the trait declared itself as taking a certain type and returning the code block e.g. foo: B => {...}. Now those curlies are of course omitted. It is interesting to see that you can use the object name instead of "this" inside any scope in the code though [something we do all the time in javascript]

Comment: @Martin Odersky Is it possible to add restriction for two or more traits, something like `trait A { self: B, C => ... }` ?

Comment: @DmitryBespalov: Yes, you can use the `with` keyword in the self-typing annotation. For example `trait A { self: B with C => ... }`

Comment: btw you can also do `_: B =>` for the non-alias case for simplicity

Answer (score 18):

There is a difference in that `this` always refers to the object defined by the innermost template.

> The expression `this` can appear in the statement part of a template or compound type. It stands for the object being defined by the innermost template or compound type enclosing the reference. If this is a compound type, the type of `this` is that compound type. If it is a template of a class or object definition with simple name *C*, the type of this is the same as the type of *C*.`this`. (Scala Ref. §6.5)

So, if you call your self-type `foo`, you could still refer to it as `this` (unless, of course, you are in an inner template in which case `this` will refer to the object defined by it – and unless you don’t give the inner template’s self-type the same name) but obviously not the other way round.