# What is the syntax meaning of "`class declaration head` { val_name : Type => `class body` }"

Tags: scala, syntax

When reading some articles about Scala, I found some examples with a curious syntax, which I might understand incorrectly

```
class Child[C <: Child[C]] {
  some_name : C =>                   // here, what does it mean?
   var roomie : Option[C] = None

   def roomWith(aChild : C)= { 
     roomie = Some(aChild)
     aChild.roomie = Some(this) 
   }
}
class Boy extends Child[Boy]
```

I found similar examples with traits.

Does it mean that I declare `this` object in a class scope to by type of `C` ?

Comment: Here's [Martin Odersky's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017357/difference-between-this-and-self-in-self-type-annotations/4018995#4018995) to this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a self type annotation.

This means that class `Child` must be of type `C`, i.e., creates inheritance dependencies which must satisfied for a given class.

A small example:

```
scala> trait Baz
defined trait Baz


scala> class Foo {
     | self:Baz => 
     | }
defined class Foo


scala> val a = new Foo
<console>:9: error: class Foo cannot be instantiated because it does not conform to its self-type Foo with Baz
       val a = new Foo
               ^

scala> val a = new Foo with Baz
a: Foo with Baz = $anon$1@199de181


scala> class Bar extends Foo with Baz
defined class Bar
```

In this case `Foo` is required to also be a `Baz`.
Satisfying that requirement, a `Foo` instance can be created.
Also, defining a new class (in this case `Bar`) there is also the requirement of it being `Baz` as well.

See: 
http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124

Answer (score 3):

One very useful application of self types is a less verbose implementation of the CRTP ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern ), e.g.

```
abstract class Base[Sub] {
  self:Sub =>
  def add(s:Sub) : Sub
}

case class Vec3(x:Double,y:Double,z:Double) extends Base[Vec3] {
  def add(that:Vec3) = Vec3(this.x+that.x, this.y+that.y, this.z+that.z)
}
```

Attempts to "cheat" with the inheritance won't work:

```
class Foo extends Base[Vec3] {
  add(v:Vec3) = v
}

//error: illegal inheritance;
//self-type Foo does not conform to Base[Vec3]'s selftype Base[Vec3] with Vec3
//      class Foo extends Base[Vec3] {
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the inheritance requirement in JaimeJorge's response, self types can be used to give the outer instance a name if you want to refer to it from an inner class:

```
scala> class Company(name: String) {
     |   company =>
     |   class Department(name: String) {
     |     override def toString = "Department "+ name +" of "+ company.name
     |   }
     | }
defined class Company

scala> val c = new Company("ACME")
c: Company = Company@56a57bb2

scala> val d = new c.Department("Marketing")
d: c.Department = Department Marketing of ACME
```