# What does 'this: =>' construct mean?

Tags: scala

I've seen a couple of time code like this in Scala libraries. What does it mean?

```
trait SecuredSettings {
  this: GlobalSettings =>

  def someMethod = {}
   ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, but in this trait what would be the purpose of this function declaration? I don't get it

Comment: In this case it is not an anonymous function.

Comment: It is a self type annotation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the syntax meaning of "\`class declaration head\` { val\_name : Type => \`class body\` }"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031596/what-is-the-syntax-meaning-of-class-declaration-head-val-name-type-cl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trait A {
  def foo
}

class B { self: A =>
  def bar = foo //compiles
}

val b = new B //fails
val b = new B with A //compiles
```

It means that any `B` instances must inherit (mix-in) `A`. `B` is not `A`, but its instances are promised to be so, therefore you can code `B` as if it were already `A`.

Comment: Thank you! As much as I love Scala, as much I sometimes have difficulties reading code in it

Comment: Yes I feel the same way :)

Answer (score 2):

This trick is called "self type annotation".

This actually do two separate things at once:

1. Introduces a local alias for `this` reference (may be useful when you introduce nested class, because then you have several `this` objects in scope).
2. Enforces that given trait is mixable only into subtypes of some type (this way you assume you have some methods in scope).

Google for "scala self type annotation" for many discussion about this subject.

The scala-lang.org contains a pretty descent explanation of this feature:
http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/explicitly-typed-self-references.html

There are numerous patterns which use this trick in non-obvious way. For a starter, look here:
http://marcus-christie.blogspot.com/2014/03/scala-understanding-self-type.html