# Why does this "aliasing" work in scala?

Tags: scala, syntax

In the Coursera course "Principles of Reactive Programming", Odersky introduces this snippet:

```
trait Generator[+T] {
    self => // an alias for ”this”.
    def generate: T
    def map[S](f: T => S): Generator[S] = new Generator[S] {
        def generate = f(self.generate)
    }
    def flatMap[S](f: T => Generator[S]): Generator[S] = new Generator[S] {
       def generate = f(self.generate).generate
    }
}
```

I don't quite recognise the `self =>` thing though. Why does it work and why wouldn't I just do `val self = this` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic mechanism is treated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017357/difference-between-this-and-self-in-self-type-annotations). The problem that is addressed here is that both in `map` and `flatMap` you need to **reference the *outer* `Generator` from the newly created *inner* `Generator`.**

If you would write `this` here instead of `self`:

```
def map[S](f: T => S): Generator[S] = new Generator[S] {
  def generate = f(this.generate) // wrong!
}
```

you would not identify the outer but the inner instance. `this` always refers to the "closest" class instance seen from the spot where you use it.

Similarly, if you added a method `def self = this` to `Generator`, you then call again the wrong `self` in the inner scope (the new generator has its own `self` method now).

---

The alias in comparison is not a method, it doesn't exist "twice" in the code example so to speak, so there is no shadowing happening when you write `new Generator`. This is just a more cleaned up way for

```
def map[S](f: T => S): Generator[S] = {
  val outer = this  // capture outer instance, since `this` will change meaning
  new Generator[S] {
    def generate = f(outer.generate)  // refer to the outer instance
  }
}
```